# ObjCreate with Firefox in AutoIt

Tags: object, firefox, autoit

I have opened IE with the resolution 360x640 by creating IE Object. This is my code:

```
$object = ObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application.1")
With $object
.Visible = 1
.Height = 640
.Width = 360
.Navigate("https://www.google.com.bd/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=jm11Vb7_Iofg8AX0_IGYBw#q=ripon+al+wasim")
EndWith
```

I want to create Firefox Object by same way in AutoIt. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to download  [Mozilla ActiveX control](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm).

> Example usage code:

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>

$oFF = ObjCreate("Mozilla.Browser.1")

; Create a simple GUI for our output

GUICreate ( "FF Embedded Web control Test", 640, 580,(@DesktopWidth-640)/2, (@DesktopHeight-580)/2 , $WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW + $WS_VISIBLE + $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS)

$GUIActiveX = GUICtrlCreateObj ( $oFF, 10, 40 , 600 , 360 )

$GUI_Button_Back = GuiCtrlCreateButton ("Back", 10, 420, 100, 30)

$GUI_Button_Forward = GuiCtrlCreateButton ("Forward", 120, 420, 100, 30)

$GUI_Button_Home = GuiCtrlCreateButton ("Home", 230, 420, 100, 30)

$GUI_Button_Stop = GuiCtrlCreateButton ("Stop", 330, 420, 100, 30)

GUISetState () ;Show GUI

$oFF.navigate("http://www.autoitscript.com")

; Waiting for user to close the window

While 1

$msg = GUIGetMsg()

Select

Case $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
...
```

Comment: I have installed "Mozilla ActiveX Control 1.7.12" and ran the code above you have provided. The GUI window is displayed for a while and disappear.

Comment: Sorry, I missed last portion of code. It's working. Thanks Milos

Comment: What about Google Chrome?

Comment: Hardly...  Try this https://ajeanius.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/awesomium-google-chrome-hacked/